# CSS animation extends past edge of screen

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I have created an animation in the background of the browser window.  It's clouds floating past.  I managed to make them start off screen so they flow in naturally but I can't figure out how to make them flow off screen and disappear.  Currently they continue past the edge of the screen causing the browser window to expand until the animation finally stops.  The correct behaviour would be for the animation to start off screen and continue to the edge of the screen and beyond, disappearing as it leaves the div containing it. Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="page-content">
    <div class="cloud1">
        <img src="~/Images/sunwave-cloud1.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="cloud2">
        <img src="~/Images/sunwave-cloud2.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="cloud3">
        <img src="~/Images/sunwave-cloud3.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="cloud4">
        <img src="~/Images/sunwave-cloud4.png" />
    </div>
    <!--CONTENT START-->
    <div class="box">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <!--CONTENT END-->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.page-content {
    font-family: HelveticaNeue;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.cloud1 {
    animation-name: cloud1;
    animation-duration: 25s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: -488px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.cloud2 {
    animation-name: cloud2;
    animation-duration: 25s;
    animation-delay: 10s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: -215px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.cloud3 {
    animation-name: cloud3;
    animation-duration: 20s;
    animation-delay: 7s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: -421px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.cloud4 {
    animation-name: cloud4;
    animation-duration: 30s;
    animation-delay: 10s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    left: -359px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

So the question is, to be clear, how do I change this code (preferably using pure css) so that the clouds do not expand the window and and the animation stops after they have left the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a css property called overflow. It specifies what happens if your content overflows an element's box. In your case your parent element `wrapper` should have: `overflow: hidden;`.

In case that does not work you can add that same property to your body tag and prevent any element to overflow it with `body { overflow: hidden; }`.

More info on overflow property [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp).

**UPDATE:**

*Overflow can be both horizontal and vertical.
overflow-x and overflow-y respectively.*

In order for overflow hidden to work with children elements that have `position: absolute`, you need to specify in your parent element the css property `position: relative`.

(In your case your element with class "wrapper" is the parent and should have position relative, note: Unwrap your header from the wrapper element.)

Here's a quick demo: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/ahfpjwb3/).

Comment: I already tried adding overflow: hidden to the page-content div to no effect.  I tried to add it to the body tag and it does what I want with the clouds but cuts off the footer (though not the menu in the header. I'll provide a link to the full code in case there's some error in my code causing this.
[link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D748338BC411C1A3!378733&authkey=!APvESJFHAGw0Jnw&ithint=file%2ctxt)
[link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D748338BC411C1A3!378734&authkey=!AMe6LvluKUvfz14&ithint=file%2ctxt)

Comment: So I thought about your suggestion and realized I only need to restrict the horizontal scrolling so I used overflow-x: hidden;
Thanks for the suggestion.  It helped alot.

Comment: Okay man I got you now, let me update my answer, the problem is that your clouds have position: absolute which alter the DOM. Updating now..

Answer (score 1):

You want to specify `overflow: hidden;` to the parent container of the animation.

This tells the browser, "hide anything that moves outside the bounds of this element".

Answer (score 1):

u can use  body{overflow-x:hidden} or body{overflow-Y:hidden} if u use body{overflow:hidden} u cant scroll up or down

Comment: Hello and welcome to SE, your answer is similar to the accepted one if i'm not mistaken  or do you have added something else ?